# Use `isin(list1)` in pandas to identify values in a column that has all the items in list1

Tags: python, pandas

For a given pandas dataframe like the following,

```
    h1  h2  h3
    mn  a   1
    mn  b   1
    rs  b   1
    pq  a   1
    we  c   1
```

if I use the filtering with `isin()`, say `df[df["h2"].isin(["a","b"])]["h1"].unique()`, it would result in the following:

```
    h1
    mn
    rs
    pq
```

Instead of the behavior that matches with any element of the list, I need to find entries that matches all of the elements in the list, i.e. the desired output should be:

```
 h1
 mn
```

How exactly can this be achieved? The number of elements in the list inside `isin()` is arbitrary, and can be more than 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `issubset` with `set` per groups for mask:

```
s = df.groupby('h1')['h2'].apply(lambda x: set(["a","b"]).issubset(x))
print (s)
h1
mn     True
pq    False
rs    False
we    False
Name: h2, dtype: bool
```

And then filter index values:

```
vals = s.index[s]
print (vals)
Index(['mn'], dtype='object', name='h1')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) with [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
new_df = df.groupby('h1').filter(lambda x: np.isin(['a','b'],x['h2']).all())
print(new_df)
   h1 h2  h3
0  mn  a   1
1  mn  b   1
```

---

```
s = df.groupby('h1')['h2'].apply(lambda x: np.isin(['a','b'],x).all())
s.index[s]
#Index(['mn'], dtype='object', name='h1')
```